# MySQL query with time and random selecting

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to know how to how to make a query that does this:

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `sendingServers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `token` text NOT NULL,
  `lastPoll` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And I'd like to get the following:

- Select all servers where `lastPoll` is less then X seconds ago
- Then select a random entry from the return value

Is this possible ? How do I achieve that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
select * from `sendingServers`
where  `lastPoll` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 SECOND) 
order by rand() limit 1
```